# ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog

I want to get the length for the maximum sequence of even numbers but i get this error `ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. I read something online but I can't understand.

Example:

```
max([2,4,6,7,4,8],R).
R=3
```

Here is my code:

```
    max([H|T], L) :- max1(H, 1, T, L).

    max1(H,_, [],0):-
        H mod 2 =:=1.
    max1(H, N, [], N):-
        H mod 2 =:=0.
    max1(X, N, [H|T], L) :-
        X mod 2 =:=0,
        M is N+1,
        max1(H, M, T, L).
    max1(X,N,[H|T],L):-
        X mod 2 =:=1,
        M>N,
        max1(H, 1, T, M).
    max1(X,N,[H|T],L):-
        X mod 2 =:=1,
        N>M,
        max1(H,1,T,N).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last predicate `max1`, `M` isn't meaning anything. And in the predicate above you have the same problem because on the moment you are comparing `M>N`, `M` is also unknown.

I also don't understand why you are decoupling your list into `X` instead if immediately using `[H|T]`. Which simplifies the program.
Here is a solution that works with an accumulator.

```
max(L, R) :- 
maxAcc(L, 0, 0, R). % list, currentBest, currentTot, Acc

maxAcc([],_, Best, Best).
maxAcc([H|T],Cur, Best, Acc) :-
    H mod 2 =:=0,
    CurN is Cur+1,
    BestNext is max(CurN,Best),
    maxAcc(T, CurN, BestNext, Acc).
maxAcc([H|T],Cur, Best, Acc) :-
    H mod 2 =:=1,
    BestNext is max(Cur,Best),
    maxAcc(T, 0, BestNext, Acc).
```